# is there any property field to disable the SSL certificate verification in spring data elastic search?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

in my current project i'm struck with the elastic search SSL cert verification, is there any way to disable that configuration ?

solution for that question

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Elasticsearch doe not use or read any properties from configurations.

You can achieve that by configuring as is described in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.configuration). There is an `usingSsl()` overload that takes a `SSLContext` parameter. You need to create a `SSLContext`  that does not verify the certificate.

One possible implementation might be (**never use that in a productive system!**):

```java
public final class NotVerifyingSSLContext {

    private static SSLContext sslContext;

    static {
        try {
            sslContext = createSSLContext();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    public static SSLContext getSslContext() {
        return sslContext;
    }

    private NotVerifyingSSLContext() {}

    private static SSLContext createSSLContext() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        TrustManager[] trustManagers = new TrustManager[] { new X509ExtendedTrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, Socket socket) {}
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, Socket socket) {}
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, SSLEngine sslEngine) {}
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s, SSLEngine sslEngine) {}
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) {}
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) {}
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }
        } };

        sslContext.init(null, trustManagers, null);

        return sslContext;
    }
}
```